# Fatal error on content save

Tags: 8, nodes

I recently set up a local version of a remote site. The remote site is allowing me to create content fine, but for some reason the local version is throwing the following error upon save:

`Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) ORDER BY users_field_data_2.name ASC' at line 4: SELECT base_table.uid AS uid, base_table.uid AS base_table_uid, users_field_data_2.name AS name FROM {users} base_table INNER JOIN {users_field_data} users_field_data ON users_field_data.uid = base_table.uid INNER JOIN {user__roles} user__roles ON user__roles.entity_id = base_table.uid LEFT JOIN {users_field_data} users_field_data_2 ON users_field_data_2.uid = base_table.uid WHERE (users_field_data.status = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (user__roles.roles_target_id IN ()) ORDER BY users_field_data_2.name ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 770 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).`

This error also crops up on some admin pages, which seems to be related: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Condition->compile() (line 227 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Query/Condition.php).`

I've done a handful of updates to the site since creating the local version but haven't tried creating new content until now, so it's hard to tell what started causing the error. Any suggestions on how to move forward with diagnosing this?

Comment: The best (only?) way to proceed is download a fresh copy of the remote site, apply they updates again, and this time check it still works after each until you find the culprit. Other than that, check the code for each of the updates you've already made and see if it could've been responsible. Then backtrack/fix as appropriate. The first approach seems like it would be more reliable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it must have been a database issue since the live and local sites were in sync except for some module installs -- same with the code. I pulled the live database and imported it into local and re-installed the modules one at a time. Everything is now working fine. All that I can figure is that there was an installation error somewhere along the way that didn't want to show itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a database issue and one method is to replace the `settings.php` file for d8 .

- Update your changes on the new file with local database details.
- Clear cache using drush.
  `drush cr`